# How can I get a list of bridges with their location (latitude and longitude) from an OSM file?

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

maybe this query may be a bit trivial or perhaps laborious, but for a project I need to obtain the bridges that exist in an osm file along with its location (latitude and longitude).

Reading the openstreetmap wiki, I see that there is a procedure using osmosis but I do not know if I will actually get the information as follows:

`Name of the bridge | latitude | longitude`

`bin / osmosis.bat --rx brandenburg.osm.bz2 --bp file = "city.poly" --tf accept-ways highway=motorway_link,motorway --way-key-value keyValueList="bridge.yes" --used-node --write-xml brdg_autob.osm`

Thanks in advance
Pablo

Answer (score 1):

The output will be [OSM XML](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) and not plaintext.

Also, most bridges in OSM are mapped as [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way). A way consists of multiple lat/lons represented as [nodes](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node). If you need a single lat,lon pair then you have to calculate the bridge center yourself.

Additionally, not all bridges are tagged as `bridge=yes`. See [bridge in the OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:bridge#Values) for a list of commonly used tags, such as `bridge=viaduct`, `bridge=aqueduct`, `bridge=boardwalk` and so on.

You won't exactly get the format you described. However with some little work you can transform OSM XML into your format.